# how to match all elements and print them in the original order

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file i'm receiving and i want to format it using xsl.But the requirement is to 
grab the elements and print them out in the order i recieve the xml file.
Looking at the sample below the first special element has got an order element and then the next one doesn't have one and the third one has one.
So i want the output exactly that way.
Thanks i nAdvance

```
<main>
<submain>
<detail>
<specials>
<spec-qty>1</spec-qty>
<spec-desc>   Receivable </spec-desc>
</specials>
<order>
<text>Test</text>
</order>
<specials>
<spec-qty>-1</spec-qty>
<spec-desc>Receivable1 </spec-desc>
</specials>
<specials>
<spec-qty>-1</spec-qty>
<spec-desc>          Receivable2 </spec-desc>
</specials>
<order>
<text>Test2</text>
</order>
</detail>
</submain></main>
```

Output should be:

```
qty 1   Receivable order:Test qty -1   Receivable1 qty -1   Receivable2 order: Test2
```

Thanks and sorry for the previous uncompleted code

Comment: Provide sample output based on your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//detail/*[self::specials or self::order]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="specials">

        <xsl:value-of select="concat('qty ', spec-qty, '&#xA0;')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="spec-desc"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="order">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('order:', text, '&#xA0;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Output:

```
qty 1    Receivable  order:Test qty -1 Receivable1  qty -1           Receivable2  order:Test2
```

Comment: Thx Kirill i would try that and see how it goes tommorow